# How to show a modal in React Native on an activity created in java

Tags: android, react-native, android-fragments, trusted-web-activity

I have an application in `React Native` where I have a Modal at `<App>` level. This application has a native `fragment` that I call from React Native. This `fragment` has something special, as it mounts a `TWA` (android trust web activity). The problem is that when I open the modal, the modal is not shown (It is as if it was under the `TWA`). How can I do so that the modal is displayed above the `TWA`?

My modal in `App.js`

```
import Modal from 'react-native-modal';

<Modal
            isVisible={open}
            onBackdropPress={() => {
              setOpen(false);
              setNotification({ title: '', body: '', topic: '', image: null });
            }}
          >
            <View style={{ backgroundColor: 'white', zIndex: 9999 }}>
              <Text style={{color:'#000'}}>{notification.title}</Text>
              <Text>{notification.body}</Text>
            </View>
          </Modal>
```

My fragment

```
public class MyFragment extends Fragment {
    private static final Uri LAUNCH_URI =
            Uri.parse("https://pwa.com");
    private final TrustedWebActivityIntentBuilder builder = new TrustedWebActivityIntentBuilder(
            LAUNCH_URI);
    private CustomTabsCallback mCustomTabsCallback = new QualityEnforcer();

    private List<TwaLauncher> launchers = new ArrayList<>();

    private final CustomTabsServiceConnection customTabsServiceConnection = new CustomTabsServiceConnection() {
        CustomTabsSession mSession;
        private final static int SESSION_ID = 45;  // An arbitrary constant.

        @Override
        public void onCustomTabsServiceConnected(ComponentName name,
                                                 CustomTabsClient client) {
            mSession = client.newSession(null, SESSION_ID);

            if (mSession == null) {
                Toast.makeText(getActivity(),
                        "Couldn't get session from provider.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }

            Intent intent = builder.build(mSession).getIntent();
            intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_REFERRER,
                    Uri.parse("android-app://com.google.androidbrowserhelper?twa=true"));
            startActivity(intent);
        }

        @Override
        public void onServiceDisconnected(ComponentName name) {
            mSession = null;
        }
    };

    private boolean serviceBound = false;

    public void launch() {
        TwaLauncher launcher = new TwaLauncher(getActivity());
        launcher.launch(LAUNCH_URI);
        launchers.add(launcher);
    }
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup parent, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_blank, parent, false);

    }

    @Override
    public void onViewCreated(View view, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);
        // do any logic that should happen in an `onCreate` method, e.g:
        // customView.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        launch();
    }

    @Override
    public void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        // do any logic that should happen in an `onPause` method
        // e.g.: customView.onPause();
    }

    @Override
    public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        // do any logic that should happen in an `onResume` method
        // e.g.: customView.onResume();
        launch();
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        for (TwaLauncher launcher : launchers) {
            launcher.destroy();
        }
        // do any logic that should happen in an `onDestroy` method
        // e.g.: customView.onDestroy();
    }
}
```

The component that calls the fragment is this

```
import { MyViewManager } from './MyViewManager'


const createFragment = viewId =>
    UIManager.dispatchViewManagerCommand(
        viewId,
        // we are calling the 'create' command
        UIManager.MyViewManager.Commands.create.toString(),
        [viewId],
    );

const MyNativeActivityScreen = () => {

    const ref = useRef(null);

    useEffect(() => {
        const viewId = findNodeHandle(ref.current);
        createFragment(viewId);
    }, []);

    return (
        <MyViewManager
            style={{
                // converts dpi to px, provide desired height
                height: PixelRatio.getPixelSizeForLayoutSize(200),
                // converts dpi to px, provide desired width
                width: PixelRatio.getPixelSizeForLayoutSize(200),
            }}
            ref={ref}
        />
    );

};

export default MyNativeActivityScreen;
```